# document.title problems in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, google-web-designer

I am new to JS and learning from a JAVASCRIPT and JQUERY book by JON DUCKETT.

I was struck at a problem regarding the **document.title** usage

I wrote a code on how to use document objects.

Every property and methods are working except for the title

I attached a code please have a look and help me how to get the **title**
property working.

The code is as following :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hammer</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>THANOS</h1>
  <div id="tony"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var lord = "<p> The title of the page is :" + document.title + "</p>";             
     
     lord += "<p>address of the page is : " + document.URL + "</p>";

     lord += " <p>Last modified is : " + document.lastModified + "</p>";

     var man = document.getElementById("tony");
     man.innerHTML = lord;
</script>
</html>
```

output:
        THANOS

```
 The title of the page is : 

 address of the page is : https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/

 Last modified is : 07/14/2018 10:28:57
```

title not displaying why?

And what is the meaning of the += in the code please help

Sorry I don't have the reputation of 10 to post an image I had to write this code.

Comment: `+=` in the code is like appending another `text` to the existing variable

Comment: this sceneraio cannot be reproduced, since the code is even working in `code snipet`

Comment: @AkhilAravind I thought lord += means lord = lord + that means the whole lord from line one must repeat when 2nd line is interpreted  why is not showing in the output  please clarify

Comment: i tried to reproduce the scenario in the jsfiddle, but it returned answer as expected, so hard to reproduce the error

Comment: In jsfiddle there are separate sections for HTML , CSS and JS so if i paste type in each sections it is not showing the title but if you use script tag then it is working what might be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually working. See it live by hitting the **Run the code** button below:

```js
var lord = "<p> The title of the page is :" + document.title + "</p>";             

 lord += "<p>address of the page is : " + document.URL + "</p>";

 lord += " <p>Last modified is : " + document.lastModified + "</p>";

 var man = document.getElementById("tony");

 man.innerHTML = lord;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hammer</title>
</head>
 <body>
 <h1>THANOS</h1>
 <div id="tony"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And, when we write something like `a += b` in any programming language (not just JavaScript), it is simply a shorthand to write `a = a + b`. Nothing more, nothing Less. :)

Answer (score 0):

your code is on, it is just jsfiddle is setting the title to nothing.
see jsbin
http://jsbin.com/yorivec/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hammer</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>THANOS</h1>
  <div id="tony"></div>
</body>
<script>
  var lord = "<p> The title of the page is :" + document.title + "</p>";             
  lord += "<p>address of the page is : " + document.URL + "</p>";
  lord += " <p>Last modified is : " + document.lastModified + "</p>";
  var man = document.getElementById("tony");
  man.innerHTML = lord;
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: because in general, I used += like a+=2 that meant a= a+2 so whatever a holds that + 2. but here lord holds the 1st line in the script so in output it displays it fine. but the second line is lord+= that is lord = lord(1st line) + 2nd line so again it should print the first line and then print the 2nd line but it is printing only 2nd line in output why

Comment: lord += <something> is the same as lord = lord + <something>

Answer (score -1):

plz check all code
given bello

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hammer</title>
 <script>

 function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML="last update:"+d;
    document.getElementById("url").innerHTML="url:"+window.location.href+".....current page....."+window.location.pathname+".........websitename......"+window.location.hostname;
    
      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML="Title:"+document.title;
   
 
 }
 
 </script>
 <style>
 body {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:1.5;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

 </style>

</head>
<body>

<h1 id="title">This is a Headhing</h1>
<p id="url">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="time">This is a paragraph.</p>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

</body>
</html>
```